# Error executing getData() on Row object - Tabulator 5

Tags: javascript, tabulator

We are using the Tabulator version v4.9.3 and when I call `cell.getRow()` in the Calculations line it returns a Row object, however in the 5.0.7 version it doesn't return, or it returns but gives an error when calling `getData()` on the Row object.

And this is even preventing us from migrating to version 5 of Tabulator, I believe this is a bug in version 5.

Below is the Codepen link:

```
https://codepen.io/danilomartins90/pen/dyzwNYp
```

When opening the link, the error appears on the console and when clicking on the "print" button, the error also occurs:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLheB.png
```

The expected behavior was to work correctly performing the calculation on function calls and also on printing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`cell.getData()` already returns the data for the row that contains the cell, so you shouldn't need to do `cell.getRow().getData()`

See updated Codepen: https://codepen.io/izmirli/pen/rNzobPG

**Edit:**

Just noticed, however, that now the print button doesn't work. That may be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue affecting the initial 5.0 release and has been fixed in a subsequent patch release.

For full details, checkout the [Release Notes](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/release#bugfix)